# DefaultHttpClient always returns true

Tags: android, authentication

I am trying to authenticate my local WebDav server by DefaultHttpClient but no matter what I do it returns true. I want to get false if the password is wrong or true if the password is correct. What should I do?

Here is what I use:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getConnectionReuseStrategy();

httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, 8080),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
        "admin", "asdasdasd")); // dummy password

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
    "http://192.168.99.1:8080/list/");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); // Execute
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an

// InputStream
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
```

Comment: show your server side code too

Comment: You have to do it on server side.

Comment: There is no serverside code. What am i using is a wifi adapter which is using webdav for send/receive files between phone and pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys i have solved my problem. I am going to publish solution and hope this help someone else too.

```
try
{
    String encodedAuth = Base64.encodeToString(
            (username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    URL url = new URL(webDavURL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
            + encodedAuth);

    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();
    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    if (code == 200)
    {
        result = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        result = "0";
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    result = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the status code for the response?

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Regards

Comment: Dear eslimaf. thanks for suggestion. i did and it always return 200. Now on i am going to try Wilson's code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I don't see why you are getting a 200 if your server requests a auth. Have you tried to make a request without any auth to see if the server gives you a 401?

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude,

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(your URL)
    try {
        // Build JSON string
        JSONStringer user = new JSONStringer().object().key("user")
                .object().key("username")
                .value(username).key("password")
                .value(password).endObject()
                .endObject();
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(user.toString(), "UTF-8");
        entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));
        entity.setContentType("application/json");
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Send request to WCF service
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //System.out.println(httppost.toString());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity rp = response.getEntity();

        //String builder from response
        if (rp.getContentLength() != 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(rp.getContent()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            origresponseText = sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: Dear Wilson. Thanks for reply and code. I have tested it and it gives me <h1>400 - Bad Request</h1>

Comment: Ha Dude 400 bad request may be because you didnt use correct methos.Just use a method that will accept the objest **User** and add getters and setters and plz try properly dude. Normally **400** bad requests are due to **The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) was 'malformed' i.e. did not respect the HTTP protocol completely. So the Web server was unable to understand the request and process it.**

Comment: Dear Wilson. I appreciate your help. All i want to do is connect 192.168.99.1 with username and password if login success then return true or return false. I am not going to send/receive any file.

Comment: What is 192.168.99.1  IP of your DB server or machine .?

Comment: nope 192.168.99.1 is wifi adapter's (router) ip address.

Comment: Okie let me explain you "you wanna connect to your wifi after validation" rit..?

Comment: yes correct. there is password in my smart phone and i want to check that if that password still able to connect to wifi router or not.

Comment: You get your WIFI pasword from this path **/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf** as plain file do simple validation and if correct do the rest.Hope i served you.

Comment: I think i am bad at explanation. Let me make little more clear. Let's say i have a wifi adapter i already know ip address, username and password and i want to check to see am i able to connect it or not. If return false then i force user to change password (note : i am not going to build a brute forcer)